# Using the jquery form plugin, how do I stop json-encoded html from being escaped

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I've got a setup where I use the JQuery Form plugin to submit my forms through ajax, returning a json object from the server (running django, using simplejson.dumps). The json returned is constructed as this:

status: [success/invalid/error]
error: [errortext if any]
html: [html-text to be inserted]

My problem is that when entering the success function of my ajax call, the html part of the json is escaped so that the results I get are of the type `&lt;strong&gt;Hello&lt;\strong&gt;`. I've doublechecked the json string produced by the server, it validates using json-lint and has unescaped html-entities. Any suggestions on how I stop JQuery from escaping my html?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to *use* that response and not [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), which will escape it like you're talking about.

Comment: I was actually trying both .replaceWith() and .html() but no luck and if I try to console.log the full json, it seems like it's already escaped.

Comment: @Jens - I'm confused...your question says "it validates using json-lint and has unescaped html-entities" but now you're saying it *is* escaped?  If that's the case it's a server-side issue, you should prevent the escaping there.

Comment: @Nick - Yes, I'm confused as well. The json that my server returns is bona-fide, valid json with unescaped html-fragments inside, however, by the time that jQuery has transformed the json string into a javascript object, the html inside the json has been escaped, replacing < with &lt; and so on.

Comment: @Nick - Well, actually I moved on to another solution, generating the html on the client side instead, but I will probably run into it again, I'll check again then, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nick: found the problem now in another spot. I forgot to mark_safe html that I was sending through a template. It was soppy debugging on my part where I tried to change several things at one time to find the problem that made me believe that it was a client-side issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert HTML fragments to html entities at server side (if you are using PHP use `htmlentities()` function)
2. Send JSON output from server
3. At client-side do 
   `json.yourHTMLEntityEncodedString.replace(/&amp;/, '&').replace(/&gt;/, '>').replace(/&lt;/, '<')`

Comment: This is correct, but my problem lied elsewhere, I'll close this question, but you get a vote for a correct answer!